# Square of integers of form

Tags: integers

Prove that the square of any integer is of the form $5k, 5k+1 \text { or } 5k-1$.

Please help which theory should I use? 
I can't use principle of induction or division algorithm or Euclidean algorithm

Comment: By not using the division algorithm do you mean not using the result that every integer is of the form $5k$ or $5k+1 \ldots$ or $5k+4$?

Comment: I think the only thing that would be possible would be proof by contradiction, but even then you would have to introduce some form of the Euclidean algorithm or the division algorithm to prove it.  Without the other methods, you're pretty much hamstrung.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Every integer is of the form $5a$, $5a\pm1$, or $5a\pm2$. Now square these forms.

Comment: That looks like the division algorithm to me.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ be an arbitrary positive integer and write it in the form $n=5j+c$ where $0\leq c<5$.
Then,
$$
n^{2}\equiv\left(5j+c\right)^{2}\equiv25j^{2}+10jc+c^{2}\equiv c^{2}\mod5.
$$
Now, it's a matter of checking $c^{2}$ for each value of $c$ between 0 (inclusive) and 5 (exclusive).

Comment: Isn't your first line the division algorithm?

Comment: @RossMillikan: you are right